# CSS optimization

Tags: css, image, optimization, gif

I noticed that Digg and Google are using a kind of CSS optimization in their GIF header image. For example digg uses this image:

[image: image was taken by the link which was removed, see the revision history for more]

Why are they using this technique and how to do it in my own site?

Comment: This technique has become pretty widespread. The reasoning is that the browser sends a request for each image on your website, and generally these requests are synchronous. It means that visitors are waiting longer for each image request to send/receive, than if they were combined. Even asynchronously, there's a certain amount of overhead with many HTTP protocol requests versus one. Once you've got your image map loaded you merely refer to the area on it you want to show by x and y coords. Sometimes servers cache the combined images, and JavaScript, and CSS as well. There's more on Google.

Comment: They fall in "webapp performance optimization". For more about webapp performance optimization you may find this useful as well: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: @double-beep i think the image that's there (now) is a mistake -- it muddles the question, since it's not a sprite.

Comment: @D_N feel free to edit the question without asking me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS Sprites: Image Slicing’s Kiss of Death:
[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/)

- Another article at [Smashing
  Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/)
- A hack to [support IE6](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/07/4/)

The purpose of this technique is to reduce HTTP-requests by combining all images.

Answer (score 5):

These are called CSS sprites. They are used to reduce the number of server requests.

Check out this nice article about them: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [css sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are called <strike>splices</strike> (or is it **sprites**); basically they load up the whole image one time and tell CSS to display only part of it, that way they avoid having to (pre)load lots and lots of images.

They add more responsiveness to the page, since consecutive images are loaded immediately.

As weichsel mentioned, check the article @ [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/).

Answer (score 1):

They use that technique so one image is downloaded rather than the browser potentially making many different connections to download multiple images.

You can then "crop" the image as a CSS background-image using a combination of CSS properties like "background-position" and "width".

The the links the others are posting while I write this probably have good techniques to crop the images.